# Selenium IDE FireFox: Simulate CTRL + CLICK on a element

Tags: selenium, firefox, automation

I'm using de Selenium IDE ( firefox addon ) and I want to execute ctrl + click on an element.

The record function, doesn't seem to record the "Ctrl+Click" command.

I tried to use SendKeys, but I can't find a special key for Click.

Anyone that knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is controlKeyDown ( ) command and corresponding controlKeyUp() command.
It worked for me:
click|item_1
controlKeyDown
click|item_2
click|item_3
...
controlKeyUp

Also, see [Sel IDE reference](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html):
controlKeyDown( ): Press the control key and hold it down until doControlUp() is called or a new page is loaded.
controlKeyUp ( ):     Release the control key.

Just found some alternative way on [this link](http://blog.reallysimplethoughts.com/2013/09/25/using-special-keys-in-selenium-ide-part-1/):
sendKeys | id=search | o${KEY_CTRL}${KEY_LEFT}${KEY_CTRL}g

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found so far is to use the command `runScript` like this:

var e = jQuery.Event("click");
e.ctrlKey = true;
$('#id').trigger(e);